# Outlook Items.Restrict Does not return all messages

Tags: powershell, outlook, office-interop, outlook-2007, mapi

I have a small powershell script, which uses Outlook interop to move certain messages from inbox to other folders. The basic move operation is done using the code below:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialname("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook") | Out-Null
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders" -as [type] 
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$inbox = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInbox)
$filter = "[SenderName] = 'Dummy Sender'"
$messages = $inbox.items.Restrict($filter)
$messages | % { 
    Write-Host "`t$($_.Subject)" 
    [void]$_.Move($destination) | Out-Null
}
```

The problem I'm noticing is that `items.Restrict` is not returning all matching messages. Each time I run the script, I get anywhere from 3 to 20 messages.

Has anyone observed this behavior before? Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: I've done with varius SenderName and $message.count match the count on outlook (also with 567 mail from a sender)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are modifying the collection while you are still in the loop.
either save the entry ids into a static array/list and then reopen the messages one at a time or use a loop from count down to 1.

Comment: doh... thanks for noticing and pointing it out. I'll go stand in a corner of my room. :-(